# SemanticModel GetSymbolInfo().Symbol is Null in Constructed Code but not Parsed Code

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Given the following code

```
var forText = "int i;for(i=0;i<3;i++){}";
```

I wish to grab a reference to the `i` in `i=0`, and then request its symbol info to see where it was declared, if anywhere! To do this using the string above, you would do the following

```
var forText = "int i;for(i=0;i<3;i++){}";
var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithKind(SourceCodeKind.Script);

var goodTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(forText, options);
var goodCompilation = CSharpCompilation.CreateScriptCompilation("GoodCompilation", syntaxTree: goodTree, references: new[] { mscorlib });
var goodModel = goodCompilation.GetSemanticModel(goodTree);

var goodLeft = goodTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>().First().Left;

var goodSymbol = goodModel.GetSymbolInfo(goodLeft).Symbol;
```

This works fine as expected, and `goodSymbol` is successfully assigned a value. However, in my program what I need to do is perform semantic analysis against an existing syntax tree. For some reason however, if the tree above is manually created via `SyntaxFactory` nodes, `GetSymbolInfo().Symbol` returns `null`!

```
//using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

var manualTree = CompilationUnit()
    .WithMembers(
        List(new MemberDeclarationSyntax[] {
            GlobalStatement(
                LocalDeclarationStatement(
                    VariableDeclaration(
                        PredefinedType(Token(SyntaxKind.IntKeyword)),
                        SingletonSeparatedList(
                            VariableDeclarator("i")
                        )
                     )
                ).NormalizeWhitespace()
            ),
            GlobalStatement(
                ForStatement(
                    null,
                    SingletonSeparatedList<ExpressionSyntax>(
                        AssignmentExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression,
                            IdentifierName("i"),
                            LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, Literal(0))
                        )
                    ),
                    BinaryExpression(
                        SyntaxKind.LessThanExpression,
                        IdentifierName("i"),
                        LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, Literal(3))
                    ),
                    SingletonSeparatedList<ExpressionSyntax>(
                        PostfixUnaryExpression(SyntaxKind.PostIncrementExpression,
                            IdentifierName("i")
                        )
                    ),
                    Block()
                )
            )}
        ));

var badTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.Create(manualTree, CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithKind(SourceCodeKind.Script));

var badCompilation = CSharpCompilation.CreateScriptCompilation("BadCompilation", syntaxTree: badTree, references: new[] { mscorlib });
var badModel = badCompilation.GetSemanticModel(badTree);

var badLeft = badTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>().First().Left;

var badSymbol = badModel.GetSymbolInfo(badLeft).Symbol;
```

The nodes and tokens in both trees appear to be exactly the same; there do not appear to be any nodes in the `goodTree` that are reused in multiple places (each `SyntaxNode` has a unique object reference) - there is simply something fundamentally different about the parsed tree to the constructed tree, but I have no idea what! Both trees have the exact same string representation, so there must be some kind of metadata on either the `SyntaxTree` or some of the `SyntaxNode` objects that makes this work in *good* but not *bad*

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there was a difference between the *good* and *bad* trees - rather than rather than wrapping the variable `i` as a `GlobalStatement`/`LocalDeclarationStatement`, it should be wrapped as a `FieldDeclaration`.